# Flattening an element of a RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark scala API. 
prods_grpd has this type: String, mutable.HashSet[String]

val prods_grpd = all_meds.aggregateByKey(initialSet)(addToSet, mergePartitionSets)
prods_grpd.saveAsTextFile("scratch/prods_grpdby_users.tsv")

When I save this rdd, I get this o/p. The first value is key and then I get a set of keys.

(8635214,Set(2013-01-01))

(3580112,Set(2013-01-01))

(146086,Set(2010-01-01, 2012-01-01))

(112220,Set(2013-01-01))

(2020,Set(2013-01-01))

(24218,Set(2013-01-01))

However, I want o/p like:

(8635214, 2013-01-01)

(3580112, 2013-01-01)

(146086, 2010-01-01, 2012-01-01)

(112220, 2013-01-01)

(2020, 2013-01-01)

(24218, 2013-01-01)

I which like to know how do  I unnest/flatten the 2nd parameter of RDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot simply convert `Set` to `Tuple` because tuples are not collections and don't support arbitrary number of elements. Instead you can map entries to strings with desired format:

```
prods_grpd.map{case (k, s) => {
  val sstr = s.mkString(",")
  s"($k,$sstr)"
}}.saveAsTextFile(...)
```